# Show that $\left | \sin a - \sin b \right | \leq \left | a-b \right |$

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation

Show that 
$$\left | \sin a - \sin b \right | \leq \left | a-b \right |$$

I saw a proof using The Mean Value Theorem, but I could not grasp it well. Are there any other proofs or can someone clarify it by using The Mean Value Theorem?

Comment: So by MVT, $\Bigl|{\sin a-\sin b\over a-b}\Bigr|=|\cos  c|$ for some number $c$, right?

Comment: yes that was the way used

Comment: And $|\cos c|\le 1$, right?

Comment: that is right..

Comment: Your desired inequality is one step away...

Comment: and what is that step?

Comment: Multiply both sides of $\Bigl|{\sin a-\sin b\over a-b}\Bigr|\le1$ by $|a-b|$.

Comment: Oh okay I see thanks

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Mean Value Theorem:

$$\frac{\sin{a}-\sin{b}}{a-b}=\cos{c}$$

$$\left|\frac{\sin{a}-\sin{b}}{a-b}\right|=|\cos{c}|$$

Note that $|\cos{c}|\leq 1$

Therefore:

$$\left|\frac{\sin{a}-\sin{b}}{a-b}\right|\leq 1$$

$$|\sin{a}-\sin{b}|\leq |a-b|$$

Which is what was to be obtained.

Comment: Thank you. That was explanatory enough to understand

Answer (score 3):

Without using the MVT:

$$\left|\sin a -\sin b\right|=\left|2\cos\frac{a+b}2\sin \frac{a-b}2\right|$$ $$\leq 2\left|\sin \frac{a-b}2\right|\leq 2\left|\frac{a-b}2\right|=\left|a-b\right|.$$

Comment: Seems pretty good. Thanks!