# $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}:\vert\cos x- \cos y\vert\leq\vert x-y\vert$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that $$\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}:\vert\cos x- \cos y\vert\leq\vert x-y\vert.$$

My try : $ f(x) =\cos x$ and use the mean value theorem.

Comment: Without in the way?

Comment: See my answer to a very similar question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2097273/show-that-left-sin-a-sin-b-right-leq-left-a-b-right/2097286#2097286). It is very similar, just with $\sin$ instead of $\cos$.

Comment: This is essentially the same as [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356682/is-there-anyway-to-show-left-frac-cos-x-cos-yx-y-right-le).

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align} |\cos x- \cos y|&=\left| \int_x^y \sin(t) dt \right|\\
&= \left| \int_{\min(x,y)}^{\max(x,y)}\sin(t) dt \right|\\ 
&\leq \int_{\min(x,y)}^{\max(x,y)} |\sin(t)| dt \\ 
&\leq  \int_{\min(x,y)}^{\max(x,y)} 1 dt \\ &
= |x-y|\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Let $f(x)=\cos(x)$.

Then you know that

$$f'(x)=-\sin(x)$$

so

$$\forall x\in\mathbb R,\quad \vert f'(x)\vert \leq 1.$$

But

$$f'(a)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}h.$$

So you can show that you always have

$$\vert f(x)-f(y)\vert\leq (\max \vert f'\vert)\cdot\vert x-y\vert.$$

Can you take it from here?

*You can also look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity).*

Answer (score 2):

since $\left| \sin { x }  \right| \le \left| x \right| $

$$|\cos  x-\cos  y|≤\left| 2\sin { \frac { y-x }{ 2 } \sin { \frac { x+y }{ 2 }  }  }  \right| \le 2\left| \sin { \frac { x-y }{ 2 }  }  \right| \left| \sin { \frac { x+y }{ 2 }  }  \right| =2\left| \frac { x-y }{ 2 }  \right| \cdot 1=\left| x-y \right| $$

Answer (score 2):

Use the mean value theorem on $f(u)=\cos u$ with the interval $[y,x]$ or $[x,y]$.

$$-1 \leq \frac{\cos x-\cos y}{x-y}=-\sin (c) \leq 1$$

Because for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $-1 \leq -\sin (c) \leq 1$.

So we have,

$$|\frac{\cos x-\cos y}{x-y}| \leq 1$$

$$|\cos x-\cos y| \leq |x-y|$$